# Why wont my truck start?

Tags: starting, dodge, electronic-control-module

My 2002 dodge durango 5.9 won't start after dodge flashed a replacement pcm. Dodge says its going into theft mode? Any guidance would be apreciated..

Comment: Since Dodge did the flash then let them sort it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had an experience where I took my vehicle in to an car audio/electrician place to get a remote starter checked and possibly removed. The next day my car did not start and was not accepting my key. It went into the anti theft mode too. I called the place back and explained it to them and they fixed the issue free of charge. If Dodge did a flash I would consider going back to them and getting them to fix it since it was working prior to them doing the flash on the PCM.